# Fileupload in Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, controller, laravel-blade

I am new on Laravel 6 and build an student application where each student can upload a project file. I have a method with name Fileupload in my controller. I can upload a file and it comes into the database so long I hardcode the id of the project.

My controller method looks as follows:

```
public function FileUpload(Request $request)
    {
        //dd('testupload');
        $user = Auth::user();
        $project = Project::find(4);

        $tmpfile = $request->file('projectfiles');
        $filename = 'member_project_file' . $user->id . '.' . $tmpfile->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $tmpfile->move('projects', $filename);
        //dd($project);
        $project->file_upload = $filename;

        $project->save();

        return redirect('home')->with('status', 'You uploaded your projectfile');
    }
```

Right now the project file will be stored into the project with id 4.
I have a table with the name 'projects' which contains a column with the name 'file_upload'

My view file looks as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{__('Upload a file')}}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <div class="jumbotron">

                            <!-- Message -->
                            @if(Session::has('message'))
                            <p >{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
                            @endif

                            <!-- Form -->
                            <form method="post" action="/FileUpload/" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
                            @csrf
                            <!-- Courses -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="course_id">{{__('Course')}}</label>
                                    <select id="course_id" name="course_id" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">{{__('Please select a course')}}</option>
                                        @foreach(Auth::user()->program->courses as $course)
                                        <option value="{{ $course->id }}"
                                        @if($course->id == old('course_id'))
                                        selected
                                        @endif
                                        >{{ $course->title }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            <input type='file' name='projectfiles' >
                            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='FileUpload'>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the id dynamical?

Comment: Add a hidden field to your form that holds the project id

Comment: If your database has AUTO_INCREMENT function it will dynamically adds id. IF you want do it on front you will need like this. `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ isset($var->id) ? $var->id : null }}">` or do it in controller `$var->id= something;`

Comment: Oklam Yaqubov, ok, but do I have to put something else into the project variable in my controller which is '$project = Project::find(4) 'How can I do it? I 'm pretty new :)

Comment: I feel a little bit unsure how I can define the $var->id in the controller. I tried to define it $var_id = $project->id but then I got id is undefined

Answer (score 0):

1. **chang the upload blade**

```html
 @foreach(Auth::user()->program->courses as $course)
     <option value="{{ $course->id }}"
       {{ isset($course)
        ? ($course->id == $yourmodel->course_id
        ? 'selected'
        : null)
       : null }}>
      {{ $course->title  }}
     </option>
    @endforeach
```

1. On controller

```html
$yourmodel = new YourModel();
 return redirect('home')->with('status', 'You uploaded your projectfile')->with('yourmodels',$yourmodel);
```

Comment: Thank you I will try

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, that there will be created a new instance of $project each time the member user uploads a file. But I would like the user to be able to upload a file to an existing project. How could I define the $project variable?